# failed to get result in pandas if two columns has same values out of three then keep first col values, else other values depending on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which has values as shown below:

```
AF_SC       TB_SC       VS_SC   
negative    negative    negative
positive    positive    positive
neutral     negative    negative
negative    negative    positive
positive    positive    neutral
negative    negative    positive
neutral     positive    neutral
negative    positive    positive
negative    positive    neutral
```

What I am trying to do is to get a result column which will have values based on the following conditions:

```
1. if values in col AF_SC and TB_SC are same, then 'result' col will have values of AF_SC (or TB_SC, as both are same)

2. if values in col TB_SC and VS_SC are same, then 'result' col will have values of TB_SC (or VS_SC, as both are same)

3. if values in col AF_SC and VS_SC are same, then 'result' col will have values of AF_SC (or VS_SC, as both are same)

4. otherwise 'result' col will have values as 'neutral'
```

In other words, if out of three columns, two have same values, say "negative" then 'result' col will have 'negative', similarly if out of three columns, two have same values, say "positive" then 'result' col will have 'positive' values, if one col has 'positive', other has 'negative' and third one has 'neutral' (i.e. all three different values in 3 cols), then 'result' col will have 'neutral' as values.

The resultant DF should be like the one below:

```
AF_SC       TB_SC       VS_SC       Result
negative    negative    negative    negative
positive    positive    positive    positive
neutral     negative    negative    negative
negative    negative    positive    negative
positive    positive    neutral     positive
negative    negative    positive    negative
neutral     positive    neutral     neutral
negative    positive    positive    positive
negative    positive    neutral     neutral
```

I was trying to achieve this using np.where method:

```
df['result'] = np.where((df['AF_SC'] == df['TB_SC']) or (df['AF_SC'] == df['VS_SC']), df['AF_SC'], 
                         np.where((df['TB_SC'] == df['VS_SC']), df['TB_SC'], "neutral"))
```

Unfortunately, it gave me an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Don't know what kind of mistake I am committing here.

Is there any other alternative to what I want to achieve as a result?

Comment: You should really avoid using `numpy.where` like this, in favour of more idiomatic alternatives.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - but why? this is a 'lean' try in coding, isn't it? may be you could help me with a better example, as I am learning python :)

Comment: What do you mean by _lean try_?

Comment: Lean as in 'better performing codes', or 'less complex codes'

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. I’ll give finding a solution a try tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and for chain by bitwise `OR` is used `|`:

```
m1 = df['AF_SC'] == df['TB_SC']
m2 = df['AF_SC'] == df['VS_SC']
m3 = df['TB_SC'] == df['VS_SC']
df['result'] = np.select([m1 | m2, m3], [df['AF_SC'], df['TB_SC']], "neutral")
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df['result'] = np.where((df['AF_SC'] == df['TB_SC']) | 
                         (df['AF_SC'] == df['VS_SC']), df['AF_SC'], 
               np.where((df['TB_SC'] == df['VS_SC']), df['TB_SC'], "neutral"))
print (df)
      AF_SC     TB_SC     VS_SC    result
0  negative  negative  negative  negative
1  positive  positive  positive  positive
2   neutral  negative  negative  negative
3  negative  negative  positive  negative
4  positive  positive   neutral  positive
5  negative  negative  positive  negative
6   neutral  positive   neutral   neutral
7  negative  positive  positive  positive
8  negative  positive   neutral   neutral
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas' native where():

```
df['result'] = 'neutral'
df['result'] = df['result'].where(
               df['AF_SC'] != df['VS_SC'], df['VS_SC']).where(
               df['TB_SC'] != df['VS_SC'], df['VS_SC']).where(
               df['TB_SC'] != df['AF_SC'], df['AF_SC'])
```

Comment: What benefit does this have over the first method suggested by Jezrael?

Comment: It is apparently clearer (in terms of logic) and shorter. In terms of performance this wouldn't make much difference, I suppose (didn't check though).
Besides, there's a question of priorities in the assignment (i.e. the conditions can overwrite the results of each other). In this way we guarantee the correct order of assignment.